# Multi dataset line graph from table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I am trying to create a multi set line graph using chart js and angular. Using map I can reduce the json data to single Dimentional array but I need to convert one of column(head) as label with average column as y-axis and timestamp column as x-axis

Sample json format o/p from DB

```
var dataset = 
[{id:1, head:test1,timestamp:5/6/2019,average:12},]
{id:2, head:test1,timestamp:6/6/2019,average:15},
{id:3, head:test2,timestamp:5/6/2019,average:7},
{id:4, head:test2,timestamp:6/6/2019,average:20},
{id:5, head:test3,timestamp:6/6/2019,average:13}]
```

Expected format for chartjs for multi y-axis output

```
 {data : [12, 15], label:test1},
 {data : [7, 20], label:test2},
 {data : [0, 13], label:test3},
```

I am able to only convert each of column data as single dimentional array but since I am converting the whole data set to 1D array there are chances of mismatch of data, if I try to directly get a graph out of it.

```
var labels = dataset.map(function(obj) {return obj.head});
var tstamp = dataset.map(function(obj) {return obj.timestamp});
var tavg = dataset.map(function(obj) {return obj.average});
```

Kindly let me know your suggestions on how to convert the data to expected format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have first to reduce the object by indexing result:

```
const data = dataset.reduce((accu, item) => {
  if (accu[item.head] == null) accu[item.head] = { data: [], label: item.head };
  accu[item.head].data.push(item.average);
  return accu;
}, {});
```

then extract values from the result

```
const result = Object.values(data);
```

after that you may pad the result `.data` field to get the right arity

```
result.forEach(line => {
  while (line.data.length < 2) 
    line.data.unshift(0);
});
```